Is there a way to get processId of client in server side for GRPC dotnet
We implemented an Ipc mechanism using GRPC and its listenNamedPipe in dotnet. Is there any way to get the Process ID of clients in the server side? The objective is to authenticate the client process by checking its x509certificate thumbprint and that requires the processId or filePath.
I tried to find the process related info in context but it only has Transport layer or higher level info.

AFAIK, short version: "no". But even if you could - you could only ever get what the client claims it to be (process-id or path isn't something that is natively and reliably available at the protocol level)

yea thought so, earlier the implementation used named pipes directly without grpc and process Id and paths were available. I know grpc is not really meant to be used as an ipc mechanism but they have made that option available without providing any way authenticate the two processes.
